# define a django model relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm writing an app that have recursive relations like this (pseudocode):

```
class atist:
      name = charfield 
      (...)

class press:
      pub = foreingkey(artist)

class works:
      work = foreingkey(artist)

class img:
      im = foreingkey(works)
```

I'm was thinking if this is the better approach to solve this problem, or if i would use another kind of relation like many to many? and for other side how i can regist this app in the admin site to have only one page for artist with works and press as inline objects of artist?

thanks

Comment: I've been recommended the Django documentation site for reference, however I find things like this unclear in it. This is a great question that I wish I knew the answer to.

Answer (score 5):

If a works, img or press will only ever relate to one artist, then you don't need a many to many, so the way you have it setup in your pseudo-code should suffice.

You can check out the inline froms for the admin.  You can specify things such as how many inline items to show of each type, etc.

```
class MyModelInline(admin.StackedInline):
      model = MyModel
      # whatever other options you need for your inline

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
      inlines = [MyModelInline,]
```

Something like that should work for you.  Like AlbertoPL said, there's more info in the docs with all the different options and functionality that you'd need.